# JSTL JSP ternary if in expression language

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

**Specifically about problem:**

I have two tags

It's work:

```
<td style="color: ${mealTo.excess ? "red" : "green"}">${mealTo.dateTime}</td>
```

It don't work:

```
<c:set var="colorText" value="${mealTo.excess ? " red" : "green"}"/>
```

[code from IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpgKx.png)

Why don't work ternary if in expression language?

**More about the problem:**

Two tags duplicates the code in expression language:

```
<td style="color: ${mealTo.excess ? "red" : "green"}">${mealTo.dateTime}</td>
<td style="color: ${mealTo.excess ? "red" : "green"}">${mealTo.description}</td>
```

I want this code place in jstl variable and use it:

```
<c:set var="colorText" value="${mealTo.excess ? " red" : "green"}"/>
<td style="color: ${colorText}">${mealTo.dateTime}</td>
<td style="color: ${colorText}">${mealTo.description}</td>
```

But IDE suggests what first tag with jstl variable incorrect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single quote around `'red'` and `'green'` Hope this will help